# Python script with bluetoothctl failed

Tags: python, shell, bluetooth

Currently working on a project, I am trying to communicate with my RPi 3 to a BLE device (only reading information from the device). I am using bluez and bluetoothctl. I succeed in connecting the RPi to the device, and can select the attributes and read the characteristics, but I would like to do it with a python script (no need to write the commands).

My issue is, when I ran my code, it seems that it got stuck at the first command. This is my code :

```
 import subprocess 
 subprocess.call('bluetoothctl')
 subprocess.call('connect E5:10:78:27:B5:22')
```

and here is the result

```
 pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd Desktop/bluetooth/
 pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/bluetooth $ python main.py
 [NEW] Controller 5C:F3:70:87:7E:2E raspberrypi #1 [default]
 [NEW] Device E5:10:78:27:B5:22 PARKING CONNECTE
 [NEW] Controller B8:27:EB:6B:EC:CE raspberrypi 
 [NEW] Device E5:10:78:27:B5:22 PARKING CONNECTE
 [NEW] Device 0C:8F:FF:59:61:48 Wifi a vendre - 5e l'acces 
 [NEW] Device CF:8E:BE:9C:C1:30 Nordic_UART
 [bluetooth]#
```

Does anyone have a solution or another way to read the characteristics of the device? (and potentially get it back in a file)

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise you to take a look at the [subprocess module's docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) and especially the subprocess.Popen() function.

I'm not sure if `bluetoothctl` is a program that takes arguments on launch, or if it has to keep running in order to listen to incoming commands.

If it's the second some untested dummy-code could look like something as:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['bluetoothctl'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write('connect E5:10:78:27:B5:22')
process.stdin.flush()
process.wait()
output, errors = process.communicate()

output_to_write_to_file = output.decode()
```

Then, all you have to do is Google on how to write the content of a variable to a file in Python. (Which really shouldn't be too hard to find).